# Is AssemblyInfo.cpp necessary?

Tags: c++-cli, metadata, assemblyinfo

I want to remove AssemblyInfo.cpp, because of some metadata errors that sometimes come up.

Is AssemblyInfo.cpp useful for anything? Or can it be removed without any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered one distinction for this file: it has to do with values reported under calls to [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.REFLECTION.ASSEMBLY.GETREFERENCEDASSEMBLIES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true). I was working on tracking version numbers of our binaries from our SVN repository by embedding the revision numbers into them. Initially I too was updating `AssemblyInfo.cpp` and found nothing reported in the file property details tab for the binary. It seemed this file did nothing for me in terms of updating those details, which was *not* the case with similar updates to a csproj's `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Why the difference right?

Now in one such csproj we happen to reference a vcxproj and that csproj dumps to a log the versions of all its referenced assemblies using the .NET `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` method. What I discovered was that the number that was being reported in that log was not the vcxproj's version as given by the `VS_VERSIONINFO` resource I added (which does get the version details into the file properties details tab). Instead the number reported was actually matching that defined in the `AssemblyInfo.cpp`.

So for vcxproj files it looks like `VS_VERSIONINFO` is capable of updating the contents you find under the file properties details tab but `AssemblyInfo.cpp` is capable of exposing the version to `GetReferencedAssemblies`. In C# these two areas of reporting seem to be unified. Maybe there's a way to direct `AssemblyInfo.cpp` to propagate into the file details in some fashion, but what I'm going to wind up doing is duplicating the build info to both locations in a prebuild step. Maybe someone can find a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

So far I never had the AssemblyInfo.cpp in my managed c++ dlls, so I don't think it is necessary.

(I just added the file to have version information for my c++ dlls).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just fix the errors?  On that note, what errors are you getting?

This file provides information such as a version number which is definitely needed in order to use the assembly you have built.

Comment: The errors are described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810827/lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-driving-me-insane ... as for how the file is "definitely needed", well it seems to work fine without it?!?

Comment: Without that information the compiler can't determine if the assembly is 1. the right one and 2. out of date or not.  The problem you linked to boils down to a mismatch between builds of the assembly.  By neutering it you no longer get the mismatch error because the compiler can't tell that there is a difference.

Comment: So, in effect, you haven't solved the problem.  Instead you've just hidden it.

Comment: I'm not so sure. With or without the assemblyinfo, if I make a significant change to the shared DLL, the referencing DLL gets rebuilt, and with an unsignificant change the referencing DLL does not get rebuilt. So I can't see any difference in that respect, other than that nonsensical error disappears.