# Linker Error: LNK2022

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2022

I am trying to use boost threads in a project having common language runtime support. I get the following linker error. error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef: (dummy): (0x01000073).

If i comment the line instantiating the boost thread, i do not get any linker error.

I tried looking online for fixing this error, at one such place it was suggested to use " #define BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL" before including any boost libraries. I tried this but it still gives me the same error.

There is a related thread, ( ["LNK2022: metadata operation failed" driving me insane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810827/lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-driving-me-insane) ) but it isnt the same problem but somewhat similar. I tried the fix suggested there but still no luck.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How about adding at least the offending line?

Answer (score 7):

```
# include <boost/thread.hpp>
namespace boost {
    struct thread::dummy {};
}
```

This helped me

Comment: helped me as well don't know why. from here http://www.svprogramming.net/news/archive.html January 9, 2009

If you use boost::thread 1.37 + Visual Studio 2008 SP1 + /clr option and get linker error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef: (dummy): (0x0100001e). Add to problematic cpp file:
namespace boost {
 struct thread::dummy {};
}

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't support r-value references. Double-check your boost configuration options to make sure you're using the correct toolset. (see the boost documentation)

Also, ensure you have the current version of boost.

-PaulH

Comment: i m using boost version 1.37 and i cannot update it to new version. Is it because of an older version?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, similar error occurred when using OpenCV 4.1.1.
VS2019 is OK, but VS2015 is not good. Error message is like this.

```
LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef: (Impl): (0x0100002a)
```

I searched struct or class named "Impl" in OpenCV include files.
Then I could avoid the error adding the follow codes just under #include opencv headers.

```
namespace cv {
    namespace cuda {
        class Stream::Impl {};
    }
}
namespace cv {
    namespace cuda {
        class Event::Impl {};
    }
}
```

Answers in here were very helpful for me. Thank you.