# LNK2022: metadata operation failed : Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, linker-errors, lnk2022

I have problem with compiling my C++ .NET project.

I have read ["LNK2022: metadata operation failed" driving me insane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810827/lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-driving-me-insane) -- and this is not my case, because in my case i cannot compile one single project -- it fails at link time. i tried all (two) solutions from that topic and that didn't help me.

This errors started to rise up just when i have changed the class to be a template class. i have Vector2Di (for int type) class and now need completely the same for float type, so i renamed it to Vector2D and changed it to use template, now i have:

```
template <class T>
public ref class Vector2D : NativeValue<irr::core::vector2d<T>>
{
...
}

typedef Vector2D<int> Vector2Di;
typedef Vector2D<float> Vector2Df;
```

And it started to apear linker errors:

error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131188) : **Inconsistent field declarations in duplicated types** (types: NativeValue >; fields: m_NativeValue): (0x04000058).

and

error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118B) : **Inconsistent implemented interfaces in duplicated types** (types: NativeValue >; interfaces: System.IDisposable): (0x09000005).

this two types of errors.

In short details: Vector2D intend to be a wrapping .NET class for C++ valuetype class vector2d (which is template too). I have to redirect all the functionality to wrappered class so i need a store its value, BUT as i cannot have unmanaged valuetype variable in ref class (compile errors apears), i use a pointer on that valuetype, BUT this pointer should be allocated and deallocated somewhere, AND I designed ref class NativeValue -- it is template too, it stores the valuetype as a reference and takes care about deleting it in time.

It is here:

```
    template <class T>
    ref class NativeValue
    {
    public:

        ~NativeValue()
        {
            this->!NativeValue();
        }

        !NativeValue()
        {
            if (m_NativeValue != nullptr)
            {
                delete m_NativeValue;
                m_NativeValue = nullptr;
            }
        }

    internal:

        T* m_NativeValue;

    protected:

        NativeValue() {}
    };
```

In addition, another strange thing now comes up. It compiles OK when i move my usage of these types from cpp files to headers -- that odd.

i have precompiled header stdafx.cpp, and i include all basic types (like Vector2D) in stdafx.h; then every single file simple includes stdafx.h and use these types.

Please, if you see anything possibly wrong -- tell me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the template definition and declaration both inside header file. Please refer [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html) , it explain how it works.