# Linking Error : Error LNK2022 metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_nlsversioninfo):

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have converted VS2010 application into VS2015, application use static library(also converted in VS2015), 
Both applications is managed c++/clr and also switched target V140 in both the application.
After converting application I am getting following error.

**Error LNK2022  metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (_nlsversioninfo): (0x02000602). ProjectName LibraryName.lib(LibraryName.obj)**

I have check both projects and it use .net version 4.0
I had look at the following link but it did not help.

1. [First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990095/lnk2022-metadata-operation-inconsistent-layout-information-in-duplicated-types)
2. [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865021/lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-inconsistent-field-declarations-in-duplicat)

Am I missing some settings here in projects ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also define/use **_WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER** macro in **stdafx.h** and check, If it's solves your error.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating we found that macro "_WIN32_WINNT 0x0501"  declared in stdAfx.h file of application is conflict with library file so we have include "StdAfx.h" file in library, This resolves the error.