# LNK2022: metadata operation failed when using 3 lambda expressions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, lambda, c++-cli

With the following class in one c++/cli project:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) MyClass
{
public:
    void Test(std::function<void()> operation)
    {
        operation();
    }
}
```

And a caller in another c++/cli project:

```
myClass.Test([](){});
myClass.Test([](){});
myClass.Test([](){});
```

I get the following error (twice):

> LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout
>   information in duplicated types (std.tr1._Callable_obj<`anonymous
>   namespace'::,0>): (0x02000490).

I do not get the error when calling `Test` only twice!

```
myClass.Test([](){});
myClass.Test([](){});

//COMPILES FINE!
//myClass.Test([](){});
```

I've tried switching off managed incremental building as per ["LNK2022: metadata operation failed" driving me insane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810827/lnk2022-metadata-operation-failed-driving-me-insane).  However, the errors still occur.

I'm building in VS2013 but using the Visual Studio 2010 (v100) Platform Toolset.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not buying the 2 vs 3 lambdas scenario, you'll have to call Microsoft Support to get help with that.  It is however the kind of linker error you get when you link code that was built with VS2013 with other code built with VS2010.